# How to make append child write html in seperate line instead of one line?

Tags: javascript, html, append

I have a button that appends an input element. Whenever I do this the innerHTML return

```
<input><input><input>
```

I'd like it to append each new input on a new line as such

```
<input>
<input>
<input>
```

I've tried creating a text node = " "
I've also tried looking for the symbol for the return key so i could append this before the input element but I can't seem to find it

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="formID">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Element">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
let form = document.getElementById("formID");
addButton.onclick = function test() {
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  form.appendChild(input);
};
```

I'm want an innerHTML similar to the below


instead of

Comment: New lines doesn't make a difference in html. Do you want to order elements using css? Or do you want to append a `<br/>` before appending input?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `<br>` element to append every input on next line . 

Try out the following code ,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="formID">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Element">
  </form>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
let form = document.getElementById("formID");
addButton.onclick = function test() {
    var br = document.createElement("BR");
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  form.appendChild(br);
  form.appendChild(input);
};  

</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Adding br tags produces an innerHTML as such
  <br><input><br><input><br><input>
Is it possible to append the elements like this
<br>
<input>
<br>
<input>

Comment: so you don't want that type of solution ? @sirgai123

Comment: This is the best way to append child node on the next line . @sirgai123

Comment: My major concern is the innerHTML. appending child then doing a console.log(form.innerHTML); shows this output
 <br><input><br><input><br><input>
instead of

  <input>
  <input>

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="formID">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Element">
  </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
let addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
let form = document.getElementById("formID");
addButton.onclick = function test() {
  var br = document.createElement("BR");
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  form.appendChild(br);
  form.appendChild(input);
  console.log(form.innerHTML);
};  
</script>
```

this will output the following in the console

```
<input type="number">
        <input type="number">
        <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Element">
<br><input><br><input><br><input>
```

the last line being caused by the button
Is it possible for the innerHTML to appear this way?

```
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Element">
<br>
<input>
<br>
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can add a div content in order to move down also the button:

```
<body>
   <form id="formID">
      <div id=content>
          <input type="number">
          <input type="number">
      </div>  
      <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Element">
  </form>
</body>
```

and the js is this:

```
  let addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
  let contenitor = document.getElementById("contenitor");
  addButton.onclick = function test() {
      let input = document.createElement("input");
      let br = document.createElement("BR");
      contenitor.appendChild(br);
      contenitor.appendChild(input);
   };
```

you can use P instead of a BR for having more space